# Bootstrap collapse "in" class has no effect

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use Bootstrap's collapse class to toggle an element when the checkbox is clicked. The page should load with the checkbox unclicked and the element displayed. When the box is clicked, the element should hide. I am trying to achieve that with the "in" class, but the page renders the same way (with the element starting hidden) regardless of if I include the in class or not.

Here is my code. I am using Django for the backend, which utilizes the elements in curly braces.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

         <!-- Add additional CSS in static file -->
        {% load static %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'custom.css' %}">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{%  static 'favicon.ico' %}">

        <title>Website Vetting</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2 class="m-3">
            Website Vetting
        </h2>

        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="m-3">
            {{ formset.management_form }}
            {% for form in formset %}

            {% csrf_token %}
                <div style="max-width: 758px;"> {{ form.site }} </div>
                <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#new-instance">
                        {{ form.not_found }} I didn't find anything on this website
                </label>
                <br>
                <div id="new-instance" class="new-instance collapse in">
                        <p class="instance-header m-2 mt-3">Add a new instance</p>
                        <!-- Form data -->
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mt-3" value="Submit Report"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The new-instance class is just:

```
div.new-instance {
        background: rgba(175, 175, 175, .3);
        border-radius: 5px;
        max-width: 720px;
        padding: 1px 20px 12px 20px;
}
```

Edit: I was looking at documentation for the wrong version of bootstrap... yikes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in` class is no longer used in Bootstrap 4. Instead use the `show` class.

Comment: @attempt_to_dev don't edit the title of the question to add [solved] .. accept the answer instead and we will know it was solved.